# Multithreaded approach to concurrently traversing a Binary search Tree by "inorder" and "reverse inorder" methods, comparing element pairs

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, binary-search-tree, inorder

There are a few scenarios in which being able to compare the last and first elements in a Binary Search tree, **element pair wise**, would prove to be useful.

For example: Finding 2 elements which would sum up to a give number. (The fastest way is trying to add the smallest and the largest numbers and then advancing each end according the resulting sum when compared to the given number)

^I know this can be done by using 2 stacks to traverse the trees in an **iterative** way. I was just thinking if there was a way in which I could do something like this using **2 threads**:

```
pthread_mutex_t MTree1, Mtree2;
pthread_t thread[2];
pthread_attr attr;
int data1, data2;
int tempInorder, tempRevInorder;
int requiredSUM

void mergBST(node*root)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&Mtree1, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&Mtree2, NULL);
    pthread_attr_setdetachestate(&attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    pthread_create(&thread[0],&attr, mergeBSTImplInOrder, void*(root));
    pthread_create(&thread[1],&attr, mergeBSTImplRevInOrder, void*(root));

}

 void mergeBSTImplInOrder(void *root)
    {
        root=(node*) root;
        if(!root) return;

        mergeBSTImpl(root->left);

        tempInorder=root->data

            /*This is where there has to be conditional checks such that execution would stop right here so I can compare varables **tempInorder** **tempRevInorder** with the variable "requiredSUM"*/

        mergeBSTImpl(root->right);
    }


 void mergeBSTImplRevInOrder(void *root)
    {
        root=(node*) root;
        if(!root) return;
        mergeBSTImpl(root->right);

        tempRevInorder=root->data;
        //A similar situation as the other function.

        mergeBSTImpl(root->left);
    }
```

So... Is what I'm trying to do logically possible?
This is my first post in stackoverflow. I hope I got the formats and things right. If not, please be kind. =)

The stack method takes atleast **O(logm + logn) space**. The threaded way could actually get this done with **simpler code and O(1) space**

### Just in case, What I'm trying to get done is:

> 2 functions, each running it's own thread:
>   **Fn1**(say): One, a function that recurses in an Inorder fashion.
>   **Fn2**(say): Two, a function that recurses in a reverse Inorder fashion.
>
> Each time either of the function reads data from the BST, it stores
>   them in static variables, and it has to check if two elements saved from the 2 functions are
>   there to compare. One from itself, the other from the other function.
>   if there are 2 elements yet, then it finds the sum of the
>   elements with  requiredSUM. In case the sum of variable is bigger, it lets the other function continue till it gets the
>   next one (which would be the second smallest element). This function stays till the other function gets its new
>   element. Comparison takes place. If this time, the sum is smaller than requiredSUM, this function carries on and the other function waits till this function gets the next element (the 2nd smallest element). Comparison takes place and this goes on till the 2 elements summing to the required target Sum is found.

This is an algorithm to find all pairs of integers within an sorted array which sum to a specified value. EXCEPT that **instead of a sorted array, we now have a BST**. Just to show, I would solve the array version of the problem by the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print_pairs(int * ptr, int num, int sum) 
{
    std::sort(ptr, ptr + num);
    int first = 0;
    int last = num - 1;

    while (first < last) 
    {
        int s = ptr[first] + ptr[last];
        if (s == sum) 
        {
            //cout<<ptr[first]<<“ “<< ptr[last]<<endl;
            ++first;
            --last;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (s < sum) 
                ++first; 
            else 
                --last;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
int test[] = {9, 3, 6, 5, 7, -1, 13, 14, -2, 12, 0};
print_pairs(test, sizeof(test) / sizeof(int), 12);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without actually examining the logistics of your question, fix your threads array decl, its one element, so indexing beyond that (which you do) invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't it zero index based?... 
So... thread[1] means that there's thread[0] and thread[1], right?...

Also.. Sorry if there are mistakes in the code... I just wrote things down to express how it would look like. I'm just not used to multi threaded programming... Especially about the usage of mutexes and conditional variables.

Comment: @hexcode It is zero index based, but the number in the declaration is the number of elements in the array. Indices for `int[5]` go from `0` to `4`.

Comment: Declared with dimension `[1]` means there is **one** element, and it is indexible by `[0]` only. All C/C++ native arrays are like this. Declared or allocated as dim `N`, the array is indexible from `[0]` thru `[N-1]` only. It just needs to be fixed, but has otherwise nothing to do with your question (that I can see, anyway).

Comment: My goodness... I can't believe I messed this up. @_@... bloody....... Yes.. Ofcourse... the index doesn't include the last one.. I'm freakin sorry... -_-....

Comment: What makes you think a threaded method will take O(1) space? Won't each thread use space for its call stack, which will take O(log m) space?

Comment: Yes, the program stack would be used, but... elements of the tree wouldn't be kept on each of the stack frames, right? Only their pointer instances would. (I'm not too strongly sure on whether this is considered as space occupation, but.. the thing is... If this method were possible.. it would make a number of methods that require concurrent traversal insanely easier)

Comment: Could you add some pseudo code? I have difficulties understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated the post. I tried to explain it as clear as I could. i hope you get the idea. I appreciate your interest in trying to help me. 
I hope it's clear enough now. Please do let me know if I need to help convey things more clearly.

Comment: I added code to show how one solve the problem when given a sorted array. My post's question is to try to get the same done with a BST using threads. Solving it using 2 stacks is the standard way.

Comment: ok, I think I understand it better now.... But I fail to see the role of threads in this. From your description your threads never run simultaneously, each of them unblocking the other, and that running until it blocks, unblocking the other. My feeling is that you just need two _cursors_ or _iterators_ one running forward and one running backward.

Comment: Yes, I could just use iterators pointer to begin() and rbegin() and move towards the centre.
But, in interviews they expect you to solve these questions by direct manipulation. Like I said, a standard solution to the BST question is by using 2 stacks to iteratively go through the BST from the smallest to the greatest simultaneously. Just in case, you can find example method code here-> https://ideone.com/QcqOGp

I was just wondering whether i could use 2 threads to go through the BST, one InOrder, the other in Reverse Inorder, stopping at every pair etc. 

So, this is impossible? =(

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that *threads* are not the answer to your problem. Two *cursor* state or *iterator-like* objects that keeps the state of the traversal backward and forward will give you the same results.

Threads are a way of coordinating execution, not a way of parcelling the code. And in any case you should avoid threads as much as possible, this being a case (threads never running simultaneously) where threads are not adding value to the solution

If you insists, then what you want are condition variables.

A condition is a place where one thread will block until other thread signals it to continue. Conditions are linked to a mutex.

So on thread1 you would:

```
thread1stopped=false; // let this start running
while (true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2); // lock on the other thread mutex
    while(!thread2stopped) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond2, &mutex2); // wait for the signal
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2); // unlock the other thread mutex

    // Now we're running:
    // ... do whatever I need to do
    // ... until I need to stop.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); // lock my mutex
    thread1stopped=true;         // change the state
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond1); // signal to the other thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1); // unlock my mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); // lock my mutex
    thread1stopped=false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1); // unlock my mutex
 }
```

while the other can

```
thread2stopped=true; // let this start stopped
while (true) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1); // lock on the other thread mutex
    while(!thread1stopped) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &mutex1); // wait for the signal
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1); // unlock the other thread mutex

    // Now we're running:
    // ... do whatever I need to do
    // ... until I need to stop.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2); // lock my mutex
    thread2stopped=true;         // change the state
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond2); // signal to the other thread
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2); // unlock my mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex2); // lock my mutex
    thread2stopped=false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex2); // unlock my mutex
 }
```

This works:

```
  Thread1             Thread2
      .                   .
   --------           --------
   | exec |           | lock1| thread1stopped==false
   |      |           | wait | (wait unlocks)
   --------           |      |
      .               |      |
   --------           |      |
   |lock1 |           |      |
   |true  |           |      |
   |signal|---------->|unlock|
   --------           --------
      .                   .
   --------           --------
   | lock2|           | exec |
   | wait |           |      |
   |      |           --------
   |      |               .
   |      |           --------
   |      |           |lock2 |
   |      |           |true  |
   |unlock|<----------|signal|
   --------           --------
```

Haven't really tried this code, so there might be problems, dead-locks, race conditions... But I hope it would give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks so freakin much, man... for the explanation, code and diagram and all...I realize that this will get me going. =D
I'll see if anyone else replies, too... If no one does maybe another half a day... I click on the "tick mark" so this topic gets closes, right? (I'm new here...)